# SQL - Select to get different sets with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, subquery

I have a table with data

```
Table1
KEY     END_DATE        
1       1974-01-01            
1       NULL            
1       2020-01-01            
2       NULL                
2       NULL            
2       NULL            
3       1997-10-01            
3       1974-01-01           
3       1976-01-01                
3       1978-01-01             
4       NULL            
4       1997-10-01            
4       2008-04-01
```

In the Above table I have 4 conditions
**For Key 1** - MAX(END_DATE) > GETDATE()(Todat Date) and also has NULL in this condition i should get max date of the set
**For Key 2** - Only NULL's so we should get null
**For Key 3** - No NULLS and MAX(END_DATE) < GETDATE() so we should get the MAX(END_DATE)
**For Key 4** - Has NULL and MAX(END_DATE) < GETDATE() so we should get the NULL

HERE is the result table

```
Result Table
KEY     END_DATE                  
1       2020-01-01            
2       NULL            
3       1997-10-01             
4       NULL
```

I should get all unique keys END_DATE with above 4 conditions in a select

Thanks

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your conditions are:

- The maximum end date if there are no `NULL` values or
- the maximum end date is in the future

This is just aggregation with some conditions:

```
select key,
       (case when count(*) = count(end_date) then max(end_date)
             when max(end_date) > getdate() then max(end_date)
        end) as end_date
from t
group by key;
```